# CSS doesnt link to HTML in django

Tags: python, django

I am watching beginner course on django . So basically  i am running server from cmd and when i want to change anything on css file it doesnt change live . My css file is in static folder in root directory.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```

my html :

```
{% load static %}
<link type = "text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<h1>Hi welcome to my page </h1>
```

Comment: In what subdirectory of your app is the css file located?

Comment: Hard refresh your webpage using `Ctrl + F5` you will see the changes.

Comment: update full traceback of your static folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reload the page and the server once you have made the changes. Stop the server after the changes and start it again and reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way exist, the shortcut to reload cache:

Ctrl + Shift + R

Then just reload page